# Amateur attempt at auction script

Tags: php

I have the following code that i don't suppose for one moment is complete for the purpose of an auction yet it should work at this stage, nevertheless, as far as i can see.  But i doesn't.  Just wondered if somebody could point my mistake.  The broswer says that the else in the php script is unexpected.  Removing it leaves the browser not expecting the closing html tag at the end.  Many thanks in advance for any suggestions.  Cheers

```
<?php


$hostuser = $_GET['user'];

$auc = $_GET['auc'];


//Connect to database

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
$db = mysql_select_db("users");



$auction = mysql_query("

SELECT * FROM auction WHERE host = '$hostuser'

");

$row = mysql_fetch_array ($auction);

$current_bid = $row['current_bid'];
$current_bid_user = $row['current_bid_user'];
$time_started = $row['time_started'];


if ($current_bid == 0) {

$current_bid = "No bids have yet been submitted.  Be the first to make a bid.";

}


include ('auction_1.php');

if ($bid > $current_bid) {

$current_bid = $bid;
$bidsubmitted = "";

{
else

$bidsubmitted = "Your bid must exceed the current bid";

}






 ?>

<html>

<form action = 'auction_1.php' method ='POST'>

<br>
Current bid: <?php echo $current_bid; ?>
<br>
<br>
Time Left:

<table>
            <br>
            <br>
            <tr>
            <td>
            Your bid:
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type = 'text' name = 'userbid'>
            </td>
            </tr>
</table>
<p>
<input type='submit' name='bid' value='Bid'>

<?php echo $bidsubmitted; ?>




</html>
```

Comment: As a side note, your code is *extremely* insecure. Look into using the MySQLi in PHP. Mysql_* is deprecated :)

Comment: Yeah i pretty new to it all.  I'm planning on reading up on MySQLi soon.  A quick question.  Is it worth looking into PDO or not?  Somebody had suggested that.

Comment: Where is the auction running? I want to [get some free stuff](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: @Ross, yes, definitely. But if you're just starting out, the OO approach may confuse you.

Answer (score 2):

You missed a curly brace:

```
if ($bid > $current_bid) {
    $current_bid = $bid;
    $bidsubmitted = "";

} else {
    $bidsubmitted = "Your bid must exceed the current bid";
}
```

ALSO, (and **VERY important**) your code is not secure. Use `PDO` or `MySQLi` for inserting user data into your database.

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
$db = mysql_select_db("users");

$auction = mysql_query("

SELECT * FROM auction WHERE host = '$hostuser' //This is bad.

");
```

Answer (score 0):

You just didn't close the bracket

```
  } // instead of '{'
else{

$bidsubmitted = "Your bid must exceed the current bid";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `}` before else it should be like this

```
if ($bid > $current_bid) {

$current_bid = $bid;
$bidsubmitted = "";

}
else{

$bidsubmitted = "Your bid must exceed the current bid";

}
```